# Use isomath with Helvetica

Tags: fonts, pdftex, helvetica, isomath

I'd like to combine Helvetica of the package `helvet` as main text font and `isomath` as math font in my custom class. Because `isomath` is a little bit smaller then Helvetica I'd like to scale it:

[image: Comparing main text with inline formula]

However

```
% ...
\RequirePackage{helvet}
\RequirePackage[scaled=1.2]{isomath}
\RequirePackage[T1]{fontenc}
% ...
```

doesn't seem to work. I tried to read the [docs](http://mirror.utexas.edu/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/isomath/isomath.html) but don't really understand them. Can someone help?

---

MWE

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{helvet}
\renewcommand\familydefault{\sfdefault}
\usepackage[scaled=0.5]{isomath}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}
    \noindent
    This is some text with the inline formula $F = m a$. As you may notice the height of the fonts doesn't match. The \texttt{scaled} wont rescale \emph{isomath}.
\end{document}
```

[image: Result of MWE]

Comment: Doesn't work in what sense?  Please add a MWE.

Comment: Added an MWE using `scrartcl`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the documentation of `isomath`:

> To improve the chances of finding a matching sans serif math font, the fonts fav, iwona, jkpss, and llcmss can be scaled with the scaled option (cf. Examples). For other fonts, the option is ignored.

So scaling *a)* only works for some fonts and 
*b)* is for sans serif math fonts, which you are not using.

Instead maybe just do it the other way round and scale down the `helvet` package:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[scaled=0.93]{helvet}
\renewcommand\familydefault{\sfdefault}
\usepackage{isomath}

\begin{document}
    \noindent
    This is some text with the inline formula F$F = m a$. As you may notice the height of the fonts doesn't match. The \texttt{scaled} wont rescale \emph{isomath}.
\end{document}
```

[image]